# List all files in one directory PHP in order based on modification or creation time

Tags: php, echo, filenames

This code displays all the file name in current directory '.'. What function do I need to add to make the script selecting files in creation order ?

```
<?php
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                echo "$entry\n";
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
   }
?>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I know that I could use scandir() instead but it only allow me to sort based on the name of the file. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: I had the same problem once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function listdir_by_date($pathtosearch)
{
    foreach (glob($pathtosearch) as $filename)
    {          
    $file_array[filectime($filename)]=basename($filename);
    }
ksort($file_array);
return $file_array;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$file = '*';
$dir = '/path/to/wherever/'; 
$sorted_array = listdir_by_date($dir.$file);
```

Comment: WOrks great i just added arrey_reverse() function to select the newest file first. :> Thank you a lot ! Me123